# Python XML Pull Parser

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse an XML file using Python. Due to the size of the XML, I want to use a Pull Parser. I found [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PullDom) one.

My code starts with

```
doc = pulldom.parse("myfile.xml")
for event, node in doc:
    # code here...
```

I am using

```
if (node.localName == "b"):
```

to get the XML tag name, and it works fine.

What I can't find how to do is get the text from between the tags. Using `node.nodeValue` returns `None`.

I can use `node.toxml()` to get the full XML for the node, but I only want the text between the tags. Is there a way to do this other than using a regex replace to take the tags out of `node.toxml()`?

Comment: The `ElementTree` API provides a streaming variant (both the standard library and the `lxml` implementations have it). You may want to look at that instead and use the end-events to get text out.

Comment: if you can switch to `ElementTree` have a look at this http://blog.doughellmann.com/2010/03/pymotw-parsing-xml-documents-with.html . It solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nodes with local name "b" for every tag with text - a `START_ELEMENT` and an `END_ELEMENT`. Normally you should receive something like this:

```
START_ELEMENT
CHARACTERS
END_ELEMENT
```

So you are looking for the characters after a matching start-element. You may want to try something like this:

```
from xml.dom.pulldom import CHARACTERS, START_ELEMENT, parse

doc = parse("myfile.xml")
text_expected = False
for event, node in doc:
    print event, node
    if text_expected:
        text_expected = False
        if event != CHARACTERS:
            # strange .. there should be some
            continue
        print node.data
    else:
        text_expected = (event == START_ELEMENT) and (node.localName == "b")
```

With this `myfile.xml`

```
<a>
    <b>c1</b>
    <b>c2</b>
</a>
```

I get the output

```
c1
c2
```

Note that you might need to `strip()` each string and you must ignore every other `CHARACTERS`-event. Every linebreak and whitespace between two elements generate a `CHARACTERS`-event.